# failure executing javac -s

Tags: maven-plugin

```
 Projects to build: [MavenProject: com.cisco.hmp:HMP:1.0 @ C:\Program Files  (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\HMP-R2\workspace\CCI\Applications\eCustomer\HMP\pom.xml]
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\HMP-R2\workspace\CCI\Applications\eCustomer\HMP\pom.xml to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\HMP-R2\modules\com.cisco.hmp$HMP\builds\2012-06-20_14-40- 11\archive\com.cisco.hmp\HMP\1.0\HMP-1.0.pom
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
mavenExecutionResult exceptions not empty
message : Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-    plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project HMP: Compilation failure
Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
javac: invalid flag: -s
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
where possible options include:
-g                         Generate all debugging info
-g:none                    Generate no debugging info
-g:{lines,vars,source}     Generate only some debugging info
-nowarn                    Generate no warnings
-verbose                   Output messages about what the compiler is doing
-deprecation               Output source locations where deprecated APIs are used
-classpath <path>          Specify where to find user class files
-cp <path>                 Specify where to find user class files
-sourcepath <path>         Specify where to find input source files
-bootclasspath <path>      Override location of bootstrap class files
-extdirs <dirs>            Override location of installed extensions
-endorseddirs <dirs>       Override location of endorsed standards path
-d <directory>             Specify where to place generated class files
-encoding <encoding>       Specify character encoding used by source files
-source <release>          Provide source compatibility with specified release
-target <release>          Generate class files for specific VM version
-version                   Version information
-help                      Print a synopsis of standard options
-X                         Print a synopsis of nonstandard options
-J<flag>                   Pass <flag> directly to the runtime system
```

Do I have to change something in POM file?

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3.2</version>
<configuration>
   <source>1.6</source>
   <target>1.6</target>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

I made sure that the JDK is in the path variable in the environment variables, and I am building this in Jenkins, and I have made the project a parameterized build and parameter I provide is the location of the JDK.

Comment: I got it working by re installing jdk.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in comments:

> I got it working by re installing jdk. –  Ronak Shah Jun 27 '12 at
>   18:40